# Why did Natalie write a note to "put Dodd onto Teddy"?

Tags: plot-explanation, memento

I have watched Memento several times to know the true meaning of its story. But one specific detail that I can't get convinced of is this one:

[image: Note to get revenge on Dodd]

**Why did Natalie instruct Lenny to "put Dodd onto Teddy"? Does it mean that Natalie realized that Lenny has a connection with Teddy?**

Answer (score 1):

Natalie knows that Jimmy is going to meet Teddy. After the scene with Teddy and the death of Jimmy, Lenny takes Jimmy's car and Natalie sees him with Jimmy's car. She knows that something has happened to Jimmy and Lenny has been there, also Teddy has been there because Jimmy has been at a meeting with Teddy.